# tkinter notebook python - click left event

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to run function when I click on tabs.

For example,
I have two tabs

```
def refresh():
    if str(notebook.index(notebook.select())) == "2":
        refresh2()
    else:
        refresh1()

notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", refresh())
```

Doesn't work.
How can I fix it ?

Comment: `notebook.bind(..., refresh())` should be `notebook.bind(..., lambda e: refresh())`.  Your version will execute `refresh()` immediately and use the result of `refresh()` (which is `None`) as the callback of `.bind()`.

Comment: @acw1668: in this case there is no need for `lambda`, but you're right that the parenthesis need to be removed.

Comment: @Bryan If `lambda` is not used, then `refresh()` should be changed to accept an argument, the event object.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to provide the reference of the function, not *call* the function. Doing `refresh()` will call the function. And when the function is executed, the returned value will be assigned. In your case, it is `None` or nothing.

So, you are basically telling `tkinter` to do nothing when the `"<<NotebookTabChanged>>"` event is raised.

```
def refresh():
    if str(notebook.index(notebook.select())) == "2":
        refresh2()
    else:
        refresh1()

notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", refresh)
```